# iOS launch screen not displaying

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to get the launch images to work on ios (splash screen) but it doesn't seem to be displaying. The app does start but is white initially then goes to the first screen.

I only have an ios simulator not an ios device. Just stating that in case the simulator doesn't show the launch screen however the android emulator does show the android splash screen so I imagine the ios simulator probably does too.

This is the error I see while the app is building:

> CompileXIB volcalc_m/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.xib
>       cd /Users/Ben/proj/volcalc_m/ios
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/De
>   veloper/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/Ben/Library/Developer/X
>   amarin/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Users/Ben/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/
>   tools:/Users/Ben/.yarn/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Ben/Library/Develo
>   per/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/tools:/Users/Ben/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/plat
>   form-tools"
>       export XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --mod ule volcalc_m --output-partial-info-plist /Users/Ben/proj/volcalc_m/ios/build/Build/Intermediates
>   /volcalc_m.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/volcalc_m.build/LaunchScreen-PartialInfo.plist
>   --auto-acti vate-custom-fonts --target-device iphone --minimum-deployment-target 8.0 --output-format human-re adable-text --compile /Users/Ben/proj/volcalc_m/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/vo
>   lcalc_m.app/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.nib
>   /Users/Ben/proj/volcalc_m/ios/volcalc_m/Base.lproj/Launch Screen.xib
>
> /* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
>
> /Users/Ben/proj/volcalc_m/ios/volcalc_m/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.xib:
>   error: Interface Builder cou ld not open the document
>   LaunchScreen.xib" because it does not exist.

I did indeed delete the Base.lproj folder which container LaunchScreen.xib. I thought that would be best so that it doesn't look for that. However it seems to be looking for that. How can I stop it from doing so?

I have dragged the correct size images into an xcode launch image set:

[image]

And in my "general" settings in the project in xcode I have specified the launch image set:

[image]

I do however see these weird but probably irrelevant warnings:

[image]

Any ideas what I've done wrong? Happy to provide more information on request. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occures because your property list file is misconfigured. Go to your Info.plist and add this key:

> **Launch image** ---(String)  value -- **LaunchImage1**